# topological sorting

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I have the following code, but I can't implement it because I am not sure how to represent  a DAG using its vertices.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#include "graph.h"
#include "bool.h"
using namespace std;

void init(Queue *q)
{
    q->first=0;
    q->last=queuesize-1;
    q->count=0;
}

void enqueue(Queue *q,int x)
{
    if(q->count>=queuesize)
    {
        cout<<"queue overflow "<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        q->last=(q->last+1)%queuesize;
        q->q[q->last]=x;
        q->count=q->count+1;
    }
}

int dequeue(Queue *q)

    int x;
    if(q->count<=0)
    {
        cout<<" empthy "<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        x=q->q[q->first];
        q->first=(q->first+1)%queuesize;
        q->count=q->count-1;
    }
    return x;
}

int empthy_queue (Queue *q)
{
    if(q->count<=0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

void initialize (graph *g)
{
    int i;
    g->nvertices=0;
    g->nedges=0;
    for(i=1; i<=maxv; i++)
    {
        g->degree[i]=0;
    }
}

void insert(graph *g,int x,int y,boolean directed)
{
    if(g->degree[x]>maxdegree)
    {
        cout<<"degree overflow";
    }
    g->edges[x][g->degree[x]]=y;
    g->degree[x]++;
    if(directed==FALSE)
    {
        insert(g,y,x,TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        g->nedges++;
    }
}

void read_graph(graph *g,boolean directed)
{
    int i;
    int m;
    int x,y;
    initialize(g);
    cin>>g->nvertices>>m;
    for(i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        insert(g,x,y,directed);
    }

}


void cpmpute_degree(graph *g,int in[])
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=1; i<=g->nvertices; i++)
    {
        in[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=1; i<=g->nvertices; i++)
        for(j=0; j<g->degree[i]; j++)
        {
            in[g->edges[i][j]]++;
        }

}

void topsort(graph *g,int sorted[])
{
    int indegree[maxv];
    int x,y;
    Queue zeroin;
    int i,j;
    cpmpute_degree(g,indegree);
    init(&zeroin);
    for(i=1; i<=g->nvertices; i++)
        if(indegree[i]==0)
        {
            enqueue(&zeroin,i);
        }
    j=0;
    while(empthy_queue(&zeroin)==FALSE)
    {
        j=j+1;
        x=dequeue(&zeroin);
        sorted[j]=x;
        for(i=0; i<g->degree[x]; i++)
        {
            y=g->edges[x][i];
            indegree[y]--;
            if(indegree[y]==0)
            {
                enqueue(&zeroin,y);
            }
        }
    }

    if(j!=g->nvertices)
    {
        printf("Not a DAG -- only %d vertices found\n",j);
    }
}

int main()
{
    graph g;
    int out[maxv];
    int i;
    read_graph(&g,false);
    topsort(&g,out);
    for(i=1; i<=g.nvertices; i++)
    {
        cout<<out[i]<<" ";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me how to read  graph from keyboards such that given graph should be a DAG? I mean this one

```
1 2 
2 3 
3 4
4 5
```

and so on.
Suppose that vertices are 6 and edges 8. 
Please help me, when I am entering graph a few times ,it wrote this  output

```
 printf("Not a DAG -- only %d vertices found\n",j);
```

please give me correct input for graph(vertices 6,edges 8)

Comment: Ah, so you have a vaguely-described problem with a big lump of badly-formatted code: let me help you with that!  Perhaps it would help if you showed one of the actual, specific inputs which produced that output, explained why you think it is wrong, and what you've done so far to figure it out.

Comment: suppose  that input is like this 1-2  2-3 3-4 4-5 5-6 6-7 7-1   (7 vertices,7 edges)

Comment: There is really no reason to pass the `Graph` instance as a pointer. Use a reference instead (and `const` where appropriate).

Comment: So your question is: if the user enters a directed graph containing a cycle, how do you store that as a Directed Acyclic Graph? Well, you can't unless you break the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can infer the correct input format by investigating your `read_graph` function:

```
void read_graph(graph *g,boolean directed){
int i;
int m;
int x,y;
initialize(g);
cin>>g->nvertices>>m;
for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
  cin>>x>>y;
  insert(g,x,y,directed);
}
```

The first `cin` stores user input in `nvertices` and then `m`. `m` is later used to iterate through the remaining input, so it is equivalent to the number of edges.

Each line following that represents a single edge in the graph. Presumably, the two numbers represent the beginning node and ending node.

So, the proper input to generate a 6 vertex 8 edge graph is:

```
6 8
[eight lines of edges here]
```

Comment: no i have problem how to pass DAG   such that there should not be cycle please help me with these

Comment: Whether the graph is a DAG or not is dependent on what the user passes in. If he gives you a cyclic graph, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: yes but   my question is  how to represent DAG graph using my x and y   points such that dont create cycle ,please show me example for graph

Comment: Wikipedia's article on topological sorting has a simple DAG that you can use as an example. If you renumber the nodes so they go from 1 to 8, the edges look like this: 1-4, 1-5, 2-4, 3-5, 3-8, 4-6, 4-7, 4-8, 5-7. The reason the original example you gave didn't work was because it wasn't acyclic - starting from node 1, you can travel through nodes and arrive back at node 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean.

Do you mean to check that it indeed is a DAG before attempting to topological sort? Well, the trick with topological sorting is that it fails automatically if there's a cycle. Therefore the topological sort itself is a test for DAGness (and I don't think there's a simpler one). So instead of first testing whether the graph is a DAG, you just try to topologically sort it. If you succeed, it was a DAG and you are finished if you fail, it was no DAG and and you can just tell that to the user, i.e. you are also finished.

Or are you asking for a possible input file which would describe a DAG (so you can test your code on it)?

If I understand your input format correctly, the following should be one:

```
6 8
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 5
3 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
```

It should describe the following graph:

```
1 ------> 2 -----
 \        |      \  
  \       |       V
   \      |  4 -> 5
    \     |    \  |
     \    V     V V
     ---> 3 ----> 6
```

(I hope you can understad my ASCII art)